# MongoDB not getting installed onUbuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, mongodb-query

I am not able to install mongodb in my Ubuntu .How to fix the issue.Below is the error
Ubuntu Version

```
 No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Release:    22.04
    Codename:   jammy
```

sudo apt install -y mongodb

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 4):

To install Mongodb community edition, follow this steps:

```bash
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```